# What happens with repeated indices in SparseTensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow, if you use the function `tf.sparse_to_dense`, you can set the `validate_indices` to `False`, which causes the function to accept repeated indices. However, there is no information on what happens when repeated indices are present.

Does anyone have any clue about what happens? The function runs just fine with repeated coordinates, I am assuming that the last repeated coordinate is the one that defines the value, but some clarification on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just found an answer to this question, apparently `tensorflow` does keep the value for the last repeated index.

Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/371